# How can i sum or perform calculation on columns in Salesforce using SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to add 2 columns from a table in Salesforce and return the value in a different column.
I am trying

```
 SELECT (UnitPrice + ListPrice), Quantity, Id FROM OrderItem
```

But this give a parsing error.

Is there a way i can do thes sort of functions on columns ?

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the query. SOQL has limitations around math like that and for example comparisons `WHERE Field = value` are OK but `WHERE Field1 = Field2` don't compile

You'll need to do the math in your client application (Apex/JavaScript if you query inside SF; your Java/PHP/Python/what-have-you if you query over API).

If you think this value will be useful to have around and reuse in other places (simplify some code, can be added to reports, listviews, give more power to admin to change the calculation without touching all places that rely on it) - read up about formula fields. You can make a field that's calculated at runtime (however they implemented it internally, materialised view or something).

If you're making a report and need a one-off field just for that report you can do something similar with "row level formulas" too.